# Scala chain of transformations stopping if error

Tags: scala, cat, scalaz

I want to apply a sequence of transformations to a String but stopping when there is an error. This is an example of a more general pattern (a kind of Chain of Responsibility pattern or Visitor pattern)

If it is possible, I want to avoid using Cats or Scalaz at the moment. If you know how to do it on **plain Scala and also Cats/Scalaz** I will happy to see the code in the answer ;)

So following is my approach *(assertions at the end of the code)*, but **It is not stopping when an error is found**. Basically is skipping the execution of the transformation X times.

```
type Error = String

sealed trait Transformer {
  def transform(txt:String) : Either[Error, String]
}

object Transformer1 extends Transformer {
  override def transform(txt: String): Either[Error, String] = Right(s"${txt}_One")
}

object Transformer2 extends Transformer {
  override def transform(txt: String): Either[Error, String] = Right(s"${txt}_Two")
}

object Transformer3 extends Transformer {
  override def transform(txt: String): Either[Error, String] = Right(s"${txt}_Three")
}

object TransformerError extends Transformer {
  override def transform(txt: String): Either[Error, String] = Left("Error!!!!")
}

def transform(txt: String, transformers: Seq[Transformer]): Either[Error, String] =
  transformers.foldLeft(Right(txt):Either[Error, String])( (result, t) =>  result match {
    case Right(txt) => t.transform(txt)
    case error => error
  } )


val tOk = Seq(Transformer1, Transformer2, Transformer3)
val tError = Seq(Transformer1, TransformerError, Transformer3)

assert(transform("Whatever", tOk) == Right("Whatever_One_Two_Three"))
assert(transform("Whatever", tError) == Left("Error!!!!"))
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When processing a collection, if you want early termination you often have to turn to recursion.

```
def transform(txt :String
             ,transformers :Seq[Transformer]
             ): Either[Error, String] = transformers match {
  case Seq() => Right(txt)
  case hd +: tl => hd.transform(txt).fold(Left(_), transform(_, tl))
}
```

---

A tail-recursive version is also possible, if a little less concise.

```
@tailrec
def transform(txt :String
             ,transformers :Seq[Transformer]
             ): Either[Error, String] = transformers match {
  case Seq() => Right(txt)
  case hd +: tl =>
    val rslt = hd.transform(txt)
    if (rslt.isLeft) rslt else transform(rslt.toSeq.head, tl)
}
```

Comment: " if you want early termination you often have to turn to recursion." Yep. This irritates me about the standard librarry. I find myself quite often wanting early termination and it would be good if more standard methods supporting these were included.

Comment: I like the recursive solution. Do you think that could be tail recursive?

Answer (score 2):

In Scala 2.12, `Either` is right-biased, so `for-yield` would do the trick.

```
for {
  v1 <- Transformer1.transform("Whatever")
  v2 <- Transformer2.transform(v1)
  v3 <- Transformer3.transform(v2)
} yield {
  v3
}
```

evaluates to `Right(Whatever_One_Two_Three)`, while

```
for {
  v1 <- Transformer1.transform("Whatever")
  v2 <- TransformerError.transform(v1)
  v3 <- Transformer3.transform(v2)
} yield {
  v3
}
```

evaluates to `Left(Error!!!!)`

However, if you would like to return a result with all the transformations applied until an error was reached, that is,

```
  assert(transform("Whatever", tError) == Right("Whatever_One"))
```

then the following refactoring of `transform` function might work:

```
  def transform(txt: String, transformers: Seq[Transformer]): Either[Error, String] = {

    type Current = Either[Error, String]
    type Previous = Either[Error, String]

    def foldLeftWithEarlyReturn: Tuple2[Current, Previous] = {
      transformers.foldLeft[Tuple2[Current, Previous]](Right(txt) , Right(txt)){
        (result, t)  => result match {
          case ( Right(txt)  , Right(previousTxt)  )   =>        ( t.transform(txt)  , Right(txt)  )
          case ( Left(error) , Right(previousTxt)  )   => return ( Right(previousTxt), Left(error) )
          case e => e
        }
      }
    }

    if (foldLeftWithEarlyReturn._1.isLeft)
      foldLeftWithEarlyReturn._2 // this means last transformation in sequence resulted in Left, so return previous
    else
      foldLeftWithEarlyReturn._1

  }
```

Comment: I can't use for comprehension because I have a Seq of transformers. Basically, it is necessary refactoring on the transform function.

Comment: Just to double check, is the question actually about `assert(transform("Whatever", tError) == Right("Whatever_One"))`, that is, you would like to return a result with all the transformations applied until an error was reached? If so, please see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Pure Scala

Probably, the simplest way to make your code short-circuiting, is to use `return` statement. It returns the result from the innermost *named* function it's contained in:

```
def transform(txt: String, transformers: Seq[Transformer]): Either[Error, String] =
  transformers.foldLeft(Right(txt):Either[Error, String])( (result, t) =>
    result match {
      case Right(txt) => t.transform(txt)
      case error => return error
  } )
```

So the `return error` statement in this code would immediately return the first `Left` encountered from the `transform` function.

### Cats

In cats you don't really have to do anything special. It short-circuits certain calls for some monads automatically, because monads have to implement [`tailRecM`](https://typelevel.org/cats/faq.html#tailrecm), and some monads (including `Either`) implement it in a lazy way to avoid doing useless `flatMap`s.

```
import cats.implicits._

def transformCats(txt: String, transformers: List[Transformer]): Either[Error, String] = {
  // It seems this is needed to help Scala with type inference.
  type Result[T] = Either[Error, T] 
  // foldLeftM is implemented in terms of tailRecM, 
  // and thus is short-circuiting for Either
  transformers.foldLeftM(txt)((result, tf) => tf.transform(result): Result[String])
}
```